# Hoverable menu goes out of page

Tags: html, css

I have a hoverable menu as you can see in the code. However, I got a problem when I hover, which the hover content goes out of the page. When I use "position: relative" for the div(content) it is okay but then the text "Example" goes to the left, wonder how to fix.

**When I use position: absolute:**

[image]

**When I use position: relative:**

[image]

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

ul:hover div {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example</li>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
    </ol>
  </div> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey @VXp, thanks for answering, but what if I set my outside container max-width: 960px and I want to place it inside that outside div not absolute right of the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use position absolute, and manipulate its positions setting a negative margin...

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -26px;
}

ul:hover div {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example</li>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
    </ol>
  </div> 
</ul>
```

Comment: It was actually what I want and worked perfectly, thank yo so much!

Answer (score 3):

due to lack of space u'r getting this issue make `width:200px;` for `ul`

```css
ul {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
div {
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
ul:hover div {
    display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
        </ol>
    </div> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Erase the `div`, apply the width to the `ul` and apply the `display: none` and hovering to the `ol`.

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}

ol {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

ul:hover ol {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example</li>
    <ol>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
    </ol>
</ul>
```

Second version: If you want everything to be floated right, apply `float: right;` to `ul` and `li` in the HTML structure as used before:

```css
ul {
  float: right;
}

ol {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

ul:hover ol {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's natural behavior, it will depend on header text lenght, it will set your max lenght for below text, you'll need to define a fixed width for the header element and not on child one as you did.
Example of dynamic width (natural div property as a flex container):

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

ul:hover div {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ExampleOfMagicMenu</li>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
    </ol>
  </div> 
</ul>
```

Second example, setting fixed width to the parent box, letting child/s element/s with auto-width (they will never occupy more width than parent, as they can grow in height, overriding height auto with a fixed one will cause overflow):

```css
    ul {
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    div {
      display: none;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
    }

    ul:hover div {
      display: block; 
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>Example</li>
      <div>
        <ol>
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
        </ol>
      </div> 
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** without unnecessary *floats* and *positioning*.

Solution with the *container* as you wrote in the comment:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline by default that's why you need to change its direction */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks children vertically */
  align-items: flex-end; /* places them far right */
}

ul > div { /* modified for accuracy */
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}

ul li:hover + div { /* modified for accuracy since the inner div is the next element after the li */
  display: block; 
}

li + div:hover {display:block} /* needs to be in order to be displayed when hovering over */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <div>
      <ol>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you don't fancy the above solution then you can simply add `right: 0` to the absolutely positioned div:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

ul > div {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* added */
  width: 200px;
}

ul:hover div {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <div>
      <ol>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
      </ol>
    </div> 
  </ul>
</div>
```